# Highcharts Initialize Zoom & Grouping

Tags: javascript, highcharts, initialization, zooming, grouping

I want to load my stockchart with a certain default zoom & grouping. By setting the `rangeSelector` to `selected: 3` I get my zoom. But I don't want Highcharts to group the data, because my Python server already returns grouped data depending on the given zoom. So I set `series` to `dataGrouping: {enabled: false}` I even set the buttons to `dataGrouping: {forced: false}`, but it still initializes with a grouped chart. This is what the init display looks like, but this is not what I want:
[image]

This is what happens if I click the button manually. The data grouped by the Python server and what I want it to look like initially!
[image]

Here is the Javascript Code:

```
$(function () {
    function afterSetExtremes(e) {

        var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];

        $.getJSON('http://ipaddress/data3?start=' + Math.round(e.min / 1000) +
                '&end=' + Math.round(e.max / 1000), function (data) {

            chart.series[0].setData(data);
            chart.hideLoading();
        });
    }

    // Initialize time with latest data as 10 minutes before now
    var initTime = (Date.now() / 1000) - 600
    initTime = parseInt(initTime)    
    $.getJSON('http://ipaddress/data3?start=1481897400&end=' + initTime, function (data) {

        // create the chart
        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'candlestick',
                zoomType: 'x' 
            },

            navigator: {
                adaptToUpdatedData: false,
                series: {
                    data: data
                }
            },

            scrollbar: {
                liveRedraw: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'hour', 
                    count: 6,
                    text: '6h'
                }, {
                    type: 'hour', 
                    count: 24,
                    text: '24h'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3d'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 7,
                    text: '1w'
                }, {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 30,
                    text: '1m'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 3 // Init Button loading
            },

            xAxis: {
                events: {
                    afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes
                },
            },

            yAxis: {
                floor: 0
            },

            series: [{
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false   //Disable grouping
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The code and the information you provided do not allow to repduce the issue. Disabling data grouping works fine http://jsfiddle.net/q7ogwb97/ Maybe the problem is how you handle/serve data.

Comment: @morganfree Thank you for the help. I have pasted the whole JS chart code now. The server side data handling method has to be correct, because it shows me the right chart after clicking the buttons. Due to the reason that the client is responsible for the initializing it has to be the JS code.